# How to search and highlight pdf file in java

Tags: java, pdf, highlight, pdfbox, aspose

I need to know how to highlight specific word in pdf file like link below using java.

http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjava/How+to++Find+and+Highlight+Text

Comment: Any general purpose PDF library should allow that, but library recommendations are OT on SO.

Answer (score 0):

PDFClown is an effective open source alternative for text highlighting using Java: 
http://pdfclown.wordpress.com/tag/text-highlighting/

DISCLOSURE: I am PDFClown's lead developer.